# How to Make Cell Shader Clouds

Tags: animation, toon-shading

I'm an amateur at blender, and i'm looking for a way to make Cell Shader clouds, ones that look like Toon clouds, or Anime CGI Clouds. stuff that kind of look like this in general, I really wanna know how to make things like this, Thank You
[image]

Comment: Try this link on 80.lv: https://80.lv/articles/amazing-stylized-clouds-made-in-blender/ Also this: https://80.lv/articles/tutorial-creating-ghibli-style-clouds-in-blender/ Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 steps to your question:

1. You need to learn how to use modifiers
2. You need to learn how to create (simple) toon shading.

You can follow up [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eL6O3qN-d4E), it will take you through both steps.
Then you can shade "the cloud" accordingly.